JsSIP with OfficeSIP (all websockets on port 5060 immediately fail on javascript)
I am attempting to use JsSIP (as well as sip.js) to connect a javascript client to a SIP server hosted by OfficeSIP. I have multiple clients using other software connected to this server and they can all issue calls to each other.
Using wireshark I have observed the OfficeSIP client connecting (using port 5060). Whenever I configure JsSIP (or sip.js) to connect via this port the socket connection immediately fails and nothing is seen by wireshark.
I follow the JsSIP documentation perfectly
var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface(ws://192.168.1.X:5060);

var configuration = {
  sockets  : [ socket ],
  uri      : 'sip:webclient@domain.com',
  password : 'securepass'
};

var ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);
ua.start();

With the above code (password, domain, and ip modified in example). This immediately fails with no wireshark logs. If I change the port to 5062, I do see the attempts in wireshark (but it still fails because there is no sip server on 5062). I have attempted to switch the port on OfficeSIP side, but that doesn't seem to work and their website is no longer up. I would use a different server software but there is no other that easily runs on windows.
However, I don't think this issue has anything to do with the server. I think all web browsers are automatically blocking 5060. I've tested this with a simple html file.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script>
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.X:5060')
    console.log(socket)
  </script>
</html>

If this html is loaded it immediately fails the websocket and nothing is seen in wireshark. If the ip is changed to anything OTHER than 5060 or 5061, the attempt is seen in wireshark.
I've seen examples online where someone uses 5060, but no one else reporting this problem. I would have also expected these libraries (JsSip and sip.js) to not require a port and default to 5060 as that is the default SIP port. However, when I try without the port specified wireshark clearly shows the attempts being made on port 80 (which fail).
Does anybody have any experience getting around this issue?

Some interesting reading on this topic here.
